# Autolisp DCL - Alignment and Sizing Tiles

Tags: lisp, cad, autocad-plugin, autolisp

I'm trying to adjust the sizes and locations of the tiles in this DCL dialog box. Basically, I want to make the `edit-box`es in the *Client* box, *Job* box, and *Miscellaneous* box to be the same width. However, they each start at different widths due to the different sizes of the `text` tile's labels. Just setting the width to a fixed value for both `edit-box` and `text` tiles doesn't seem to be fixing the issue for me. How do I need to change this code to make the tiles within this dialog box uniform?

As a bonus, I want to also adjust the tiles in the *Revision* box. I'm assuming this will be using the same solution. I want to have the widths of the `edit-box`es of different widths with the labels centered above them.

I have found that DCL files are a slow and painful process for me. Any help with building this dialog box would be helpful. Thank you for your time.

[image: Current DCL file layout]

**AutoLisp Code:**

```lisp
(defun C:Test01 (/ sPathAndName sDCLModuleName dclFile bContinue)
    
    ;; Initializing
    (setq sPathAndName "[File's location and name]")
    (setq sDCLModuleName "TitleRevUpdate")
    (setq bContinue T)

    ;; File Exists
    (if (not (findfile sPathAndName))(progn 
        (princ "\nError: The DCL file was not found.\n")
        (setq bContinue nil)
    ));if<-progn
    
    ;;  DCL File
    (if bContinue (progn
        (setq dclFile (load_dialog sPathAndName))
        (if (>= 0 dclFile)(progn 
            (princ "\nError: DCL file cannot be loaded.\n")
            (setq bContinue nil)
        ));if<-progn
    ));if<-progn

    ;; Creating a new module
    (if bContinue 
        (setq bContinue (new_dialog sDCLModuleName dclFile "" '(-1 -1)))
    );if

    ;; Build and run DCL module
    (if bContinue (progn
        ;; User Form
        (princ "\nstart_dialog : ")(princ (start_dialog))(terpri)
        (unload_dialog dclFile)
    ));if<-progn
);C:Test01
```

**DCL Code:**

```lisp
TitleRevUpdate : dialog {
    key = "Title" ;
    label = "Update Title Block and Revision" ;

    // Title
    : boxed_column {
        key = "Column_TitleBoxes" ;
        label = "Title" ;
        
        // Client
        : boxed_column {
            key = "Client_Box" ;
            label = "Client" ;
            : row { // Row 01 - Name
                key = "Row_Client_Name" ;
                width = 15 ;
                : text {
                    key = "txt_Client_Name" ;
                    alignment = right ;
                    label = "Client's Name" ;
                    width = 10 ;
                }// text
                : edit_box {
                    key = "edbx_Client_Name" ;
                    alignment = left ;
                    width = 10 ;
                }// edit_box
            } //row
            : row { // Row 02 - Location
                key = "Row_Client_Loc" ;
                : text {
                    key = "txt_Client_Loc" ;
                    alignment = right ;
                    label = "Client's Location" ;
                    width = 10 ;
                }// text
                : edit_box {
                    key = "edbx_Client_Loc" ;
                    alignment = left ;
                    width = 10 ;
                }// edit_box
            } //row
        } //boxed_column
        : spacer {
        }// spacer
        
        // Job
        : boxed_column {
            key = "Job_Box" ;
            label = "Job" ;
            : row { // Row 03 - Name
                key = "Row_Job_Name" ;
                : text {
                    key = "txt_Job_Name" ;
                    label = "Job's Name" ;
                }// text
                : edit_box {
                    key = "edbx_Job_Name" ;
                }// edit_box
            } //row
            : row { // Row 04 - Number
                key = "Row_Job_Number" ;
                : text {
                    key = "txt_Job_Number" ;
                    label = "Job's Number" ;
                }// text
                : edit_box {
                    key = "edbx_Job_Number" ;
                }// edit_box
            } //row
        } //boxed_column
        : spacer {
        }// spacer
        
        // Miscellaneous
        : boxed_column {
            key = "Miscellaneous_Box" ;
            label = "Miscellaneous" ;
            : row { // Row 05 - Creator's Initials
                key = "Row_Creator_Name" ;
                : text {
                    key = "txt_Creator_Name" ;
                    label = "Creator's Name" ;
                }// text
                : edit_box {
                    key = "edbx_Creator_Name" ;
                }// edit_box
            } //row
            : row { // Row 06 - Date of Creation
                key = "Row_Date" ;
                : text {
                    key = "txt_TitleDate" ;
                    label = "Date" ;
                }// text
                : edit_box {
                    key = "edbx_TitleDate" ;
                }// edit_box
            } //row
            : row { // Row 07 - Issued For
                key = "Row_Issued_For" ;
                : text {
                    key = "txt_Issued_For" ;
                    label = "Issued For" ;
                }// text
                : edit_box {
                    key = "edbx_Issued_For" ;
                }// edit_box
            } //row
        } //boxed_column
    } //boxed_column
    : spacer {
    }// spacer
    
    // Revision
    : boxed_column {
        key = "Column_Revision" ;
        label = "Revision" ;
        : row { // Row 08 - Quick Choices
            key = "Row_Buttons" ;
            : button {
                key = "btn_IFC" ;
                label = "Issued for Construction" ;
            }// button
            : button {
                key = "tbn_AB" ;
                label = "As Built" ;
            }// button
            : radio_column {
                key = "RadioCol_WriteMethod" ;
                : radio_button {
                    key = "rbtn_Owt" ;
                    label = "Clear && Overwrite" ;
                }// radio_button
                : radio_button {
                    key = "rbtn_Apnd" ;
                    label = "Append / New Line" ;
                }// radio_button
            } //radio_column
        } //row
        : spacer {
        }// spacer
        : row { // Row 09 - Rev Labels
            key = "Row_Labels" ;
            : text {
                key = "txt_Rev" ;
                label = "Rev" ;
            }// text
            : text {
                key = "txt_Initials" ;
                label = "Initials" ;
            }// text
            : text {
                key = "txt_Description" ;
                label = "Description" ;
            }// text
            : text {
                key = "txt_RevDate" ;
                label = "Date" ;
            }// text
        } //row
        : row { // Row 10 - Rev Edit Boxes
            key = "Row_Rev" ;
            : edit_box {
                key = "edbx_Rev" ;
            }// edit_box
            : edit_box {
                key = "edbx_Initials" ;
            }// edit_box
            : edit_box {
                key = "edbx_Date" ;
            }// edit_box
            : edit_box {
                key = "edbx_RevDate" ;
            }// edit_box
        } //row
    } //boxed_column
    : spacer {
    }// spacer
    
    // Return Commands
    : row { // Row 11 - Buttons
        key = "Row_Return" ;
        : button {
            key = "btn_DWGs" ;
            action = "(done_dialog 2)" ;
            label = "Show Drawings" ;
        }// button
        : button {
            key = "btn_Confirm" ;
            action = "(done_dialog 1)" ;
            is_enabled = true ;
            label = "Confirm" ;
        }// button
        : button {
            key = "btn_Cancel" ;
            action = "(done_dialog 0)" ;
            is_default = true ;
            label = "Cancel" ;
        }// button
    } //row
    : spacer {
    }// spacer

} // TitleRevUpdate
```

Comment: And yes. DCL is difficult. A long time ago I used ObjectDCL and OpenDCL to make work DCL easier. I don't know if it's still avaliable

Comment: I've tried OpenDCL, but it doesn't work with DraftSight, so I'm back with the vanilla DCL. However, I have yet to try ObjectDCL. I'll have to look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to edit box alignment in standard DCL is to set the `width` attribute to be the same for all edit boxes (and large enough to accommodate the text and editing area of the largest edit box in the group), set the `fixed_width` attribute to `true` for all edit boxes, and then control the size of the edit box itself using the `edit_width` attribute.

You don't need separate `text` tiles when working with edit boxes, instead, you can use the `label` attribute of the `edit_box` tile.

For example, the upper section of your DCL could be revised to the following:

```lisp
TitleRevUpdate : dialog
{
    key = "Title" ;
    label = "Update Title Block and Revision" ;
    spacer;

    // Title
    : boxed_column
    {
        label = "Title" ;
      
        // Client
        : boxed_column
        {
            label = "Client" ;
            : edit_box
            {
                label = "Client's Name:";
                key = "edbx_Client_Name";
                alignment = left;
                width = 52;
                fixed_width = true;
                edit_width = 30;
            }
            : edit_box
            {
                label = "Client's Location:" ;
                key = "edbx_Client_Loc" ;
                alignment = left;
                width = 52;
                fixed_width = true;
                edit_width = 30;
            }
            spacer;
        }
        spacer;
        
        // Job
        : boxed_column
        {
            label = "Job";
            : edit_box
            {
                label = "Job's Name:";
                key = "edbx_Job_Name";
                alignment = left;
                width = 52;
                fixed_width = true;
                edit_width = 30;
            }
            : edit_box
            {
                label = "Job's Number:" ;
                key = "edbx_Job_Number" ;
                alignment = left;
                width = 52;
                fixed_width = true;
                edit_width = 30;
            }
            spacer;
        }
        spacer;
        
        // Miscellaneous
        : boxed_column
        {
            label = "Miscellaneous" ;
            : edit_box
            {
                key = "edbx_Creator_Name" ;
                label = "Creator's Name:" ;
                alignment = left;
                width = 52;
                fixed_width = true;
                edit_width = 30;
            }
            : edit_box 
            {
                key = "edbx_TitleDate" ;
                label = "Date:" ;
                alignment = left;
                width = 52;
                fixed_width = true;
                edit_width = 30;
            }
            : edit_box 
            {
                key = "edbx_Issued_For" ;
                label = "Issued For:" ;
                alignment = left;
                width = 52;
                fixed_width = true;
                edit_width = 30;
            }
            spacer;
        }
        spacer;
    }
    spacer;
        
    // Return Commands
    : row
    {
        key = "Row_Return" ;
        fixed_width = true;
        alignment = centered;
        : button 
        {
            key = "btn_DWGs" ;
            action = "(done_dialog 2)" ;
            label = "Drawings" ;
            fixed_width = true;
            width = 16;
        }
        : button 
        {
            key = "btn_Confirm" ;
            action = "(done_dialog 1)" ;
            is_enabled = true ;
            label = "Confirm" ;
            fixed_width = true;
            width = 16;
        }
        : button 
        {
            key = "btn_Cancel" ;
            action = "(done_dialog 0)" ;
            is_default = true ;
            label = "Cancel" ;
            fixed_width = true;
            width = 16;
        }
    }
    spacer;
}
```

To yield the following GUI:

[image: GUI]

And given that all of the tiles are sharing the same attribute values, you can define a named tile to condense the code much further, e.g.:

```lisp
myeditbox : edit_box
{
    alignment = left;
    width = 52;
    fixed_width = true;
    edit_width = 30;
}
mybutton : button
{
    fixed_width = true;
    width = 16;
}
TitleRevUpdate : dialog
{
    key = "Title" ;
    label = "Update Title Block and Revision" ;
    spacer;
    : boxed_column
    {
        label = "Title" ;
        : boxed_column
        {
            label = "Client" ;
            : myeditbox { label = "Client's Name:";     key = "edbx_Client_Name"; }
            : myeditbox { label = "Client's Location:"; key = "edbx_Client_Loc" ; }
            spacer;
        }
        spacer;
        : boxed_column
        {
            label = "Job";
            : myeditbox { label = "Job's Name:";   key = "edbx_Job_Name";   }
            : myeditbox { label = "Job's Number:"; key = "edbx_Job_Number"; }
            spacer;
        }
        spacer;
        : boxed_column
        {
            label = "Miscellaneous" ;
            : myeditbox { label = "Creator's Name:"; key = "edbx_Creator_Name"; }
            : myeditbox { label = "Date:";           key = "edbx_TitleDate";    }
            : myeditbox { label = "Issued For:";     key = "edbx_Issued_For";   }
            spacer;
        }
        spacer;
    }
    spacer;
    : row
    {
        key = "Row_Return" ;
        fixed_width = true;
        alignment = centered;
        : mybutton { key = "btn_DWGs";    action = "(done_dialog 2)"; label = "Drawings"; }
        : mybutton { key = "btn_Confirm"; action = "(done_dialog 1)"; label = "Confirm"; is_enabled = true; }
        : mybutton { key = "btn_Cancel" ; action = "(done_dialog 0)"; label = "Cancel";  is_default = true; }
    }
    spacer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @LeeMac! I did not know that the code could be condensed in this way. I'll definately keep this in mind as I continue building these dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

Except

```
width = 10 ;
```

You need also

```
fixed_width = true;
```

on each `edit_box`